# How to configure Apache 2.2 to forward all subdomains to Tomcat except the root domain

Tags: apache, tomcat, wildcard-subdomain

I have a Tomcat application that is running behind Apache 2.2. My current setup forwards all incoming requests to Tomcat. What I want is to make Apache Web Server forward only the subdomains, not the root domain to Tomcat.

For Example:

Assuming that www.myfakedomain.com is my domain name, I want to make *.myfakedomain.com forwarded to Tomcat while www.myfakedomain.com be served with Apache Web server without the involvement of Tomcat.

That is what I have now (it forwards all requests to Tomcat):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@myfakedomain.com
     ServerName www.myfakedomain.com

     JkMount /* mytomcat
</VirtualHost>
```

I must also mentioned that I do not want to create a separate entry for every subdomain, I want to capture all. I would appreciate any pointers!

Thank You!

Comment: You need to create at least two vhosts in Apache, one for your main site, and one for the subdomains which can contain the JkMount to tomcat. You can do wildcard subdomains with named virtual hosts: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: Thank you! The documentation helped a lot. I used `NameVirtualHost` and that solved my problem.